# Why did Edward's eyes not turn red when he feeds on human blood?

Tags: twilight

It is said that when a vampire drinks human blood, its eyes turn red. How come Edward's eyes did not turn red after drinking Bella's blood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we know that all vamps in the Twilight universe are, by default, red at the time of their transformation from human to vampire.  We know that vampires who drink human blood continue to have red eyes.  Those who choose to become vegetarians have eyes that eventually change colors and become golden (unless they haven't fed in awhile and then they become black).

However, the change from red to golden isn't immediate the first time a vamp drinks animal blood.  I believe this is discussed more in *Breaking Dawn*.  I would imagine the same would be true for a vampire who has been a long-time "vegetarian" and, for one reason or another, ingests human blood.  One time drinking human blood doesn't change eye color, but a consistent diet of human blood would.

Comment: Breaking Dawn, chapter 20: "The eyes?" I whispered, unwilling to say *my eyes*. "How long?" "They'll darken up in a few months," Edward said in a soft comforting voice. "Animal blood dilutes the color more quickly than a diet of human blood. They'll turn amber first, then gold."

Comment: I was trying to avoid any kind of spoiler since the OP was asking only Twilight-related questions and I wasn't sure if he'd read/seen the other books/movies, but it appears that he has so thanks for looking that up for me! :-D

Answer (score 0):

We know that the Cullen family only eats animal blood which is why they have golden eyes. The reason Bella's eyes are red at first is that even if you don't drink blood immediately your eyes still turn red. After you consistently feed on animal blood your eyes will turn golden. The reason Edward's eyes don't turn red is because he is not consistently eating human blood.

Comment: I've corrected a few mistakes in the post and fixed up the grammar. I've also edited to answer the actual question along the same line of reasoning you appear to have been using but never made explicit. Here we require answers to be answer to the actual question asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you read *Midnight Sun*, it says that his eyes were red, but only for a while, and it faded. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You could make this a much better answer if you could find and include the exact quote.

Answer (score 0):

In Midnight Sun, Chapter 24, Blood, it shows that Edward had red eyes and that he used contacts to cover up.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] to include the exact quote from *Midnight Sun* to support this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Vampire not only have red or golden eyes color, it is said that they also have blue,green, etc.  The color of their eyes show their best vampire power, for example, if a vampire have green eyes, they are very good in speed and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  We appreciate your answer, but could you please add some references as to where you source this information from to strengthen your points?  Thanks